# Interpreting the hazard ratio for time dependent coefficient

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am learning the Cox model following following helpful advice from Therneau, Crowson and Atkinson. I am having some trouble interpreting the hazard ratios. In the "Using Time Dependent Covariates and Time Dependent Coefficients in the Cox Mode", a flexible fit by using nature spline was set as the time-transform functionality. I am using the Survival package version 3.4_0 and R version 4.1.0.

```
> vfit4 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno),
data=veteran,
tt = function(x, t, ...) x* nsk(t, knots=c(5, 100, 200, 400),
Boundary.knots = FALSE))
>vfit4
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno),
data = veteran, tt = function(x, t, ...) x * nsk(t, knots = c(5,
100, 200, 400), Boundary.knots = FALSE))
          coef      exp(coef) se(coef)     z      p
trt       -0.025937 0.974397 0.191034 -0.136 0.892003
prior     -0.005787 0.994229 0.020299 -0.285 0.775556
karno     -0.059583 0.942157 0.009414 -6.329 2.46e-10
tt(karno)1 0.048253 1.049436 0.016281 2.964 0.003039
tt(karno)2 0.062323 1.064306 0.016736 3.724 0.000196
tt(karno)3 0.040798 1.041642 0.020558 1.985 0.047197
Likelihood ratio test=59.02 on 6 df, p=7.111e-11
n= 137, number of events= 128
```

I do not know what is the interpretation of the  HR of karno.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried reproducing your code with Survival package version 3.3_1 and R version 4.2.0 and got different results. In particular, I only got a single coefficient for tt(karno), not 3 coefficients. Please edit the question to specify what software versions you are using.

Comment: @EdM Thank you for your reply. I am using the Survival package version 3.4_0 and R version 4.1.0. The code above were available in the  vignette of Terry Therneau (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) (Page 23).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that there was an update to the vignette since the  last version I had downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The HR for `karno` represents what might be considered the linear part of the association between `karno` and outcome. In this type of model you need to interpret it together with the additional terms from the `tt()` function.

More precisely, the coefficient for `karno` is a time-independent change in log-hazard per unit change in `karno`, to which you add the corrections from the time-dependent `tt()` function to get the full association of `karno` with outcome.